# R: Argument as variablename and string in function?

Tags: r, effects

I would like to create a function for the effect on a multinomial model. The Effect function requires a string with the predictor name and the predictor itself. I have tried different ways to convert the argument into a string, but I get the same error: 
"the following predictor is not in the model: activity" when calling for minmax(activity,model1). But it is. What am I doing wrong?

```
# effects when minimum und maximum ####
# minmax function
minmax <- function(x1,m){
      Effect(paste0('"',deparse(substitute(x1)),'"'),m,xlevels=list(x=c(min(x1),max(x1))    ))
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I found a solution, different from the linked solution:   [code] (as.character(deparse(substitute(x1))))